# How to do a integer division of a long int in c?

Tags: c, bitstuffing

So i  am writing  a  code for Bit Stuffing in C.  What I am trying to do is take an  input from user,keep on dividing  the number to get each digit using "%" operator.This works as long  as the no is in the range of  int. If I use long int type,the  code  no  longer  works  mostly  because the "n/10" is no longer an integer.So how do I do an integer division of the long int type variable.In python "//" used to work for this purpose.Anything similar in C? 
And I don't want to use an array  because in that case the user has to input one digit at  a  time.Here's my code for reference.Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int c,n,m,bit[200]={0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0},x=7,count=0,ch=0;

    do{
        printf("Enter No:\n");
        scanf("%d",&n);
        m=n;
        while(m>0){
            c=m%10;
            m=m/10;
            if(c==1){
                count++;
            }
            else if(c==0){
                count=0;
            }
            else if(c>1 && c<10){
                printf("Invalid  Pattern.Enter Either 1 or 0.\n");
                ch=1;
                break;
            }
            ch=0;
            x++;
            bit[x]=c;
            if(count==5){x++;bit[x]=0;count=0;}
        }

    }while(ch==1);

    x++;
    bit[x]=0;
    for(int i=0;i<=5;i++){
        x++;
        bit[x]=1;
    }
    x++;
    bit[x]=0;
    for(int i=0;i<=x;i++){
        printf("%d",bit[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `long c;` (or, C99, `long long c;`) for a larger limit. To scan a `long` use `"%ld"` (`"%lld"` for long long). To print a `long` use `"%ld"` (`"%lld"` for long long)

Comment: As long as you use `long` for all your intermediate results you should be fine.

Comment: "*...  because the "n/10" is no longer an integer*" - why would `n/10` no longer be an integer?

Comment: Integer division works just fine for all integer types, including `long int` in particular.  Ditto the modulus operator.  Your problem is likely that you are not *inputting* your value into a `long int` correctly (but we don't know, because you've not presented a version of your code that attempts to do so).

Comment: Since you have `scanf("%d",&n);` and `n` is an `int`, you can't get a value outside the range of `int` into `n`, so the question is moot on that point.  It isn't even interesting to ask what happens if you type a value for `n` that is too big — that is simply undefined behaviour (in the [`scanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html)
function).

Comment: You should really be reading the user input as a string instead of an integer.  Then you won't be limited to the range of any integer type and you can enter bit patterns that start with one ore more zeros.

Comment: Post sample input and example outputs to add clarity.